# Should i index a colum part of primary key

Tags: indexing, sqlite

I'm well aware that an index is automatically created with a primary key.
Nevertheless what about multi column primary key ?

Lets say i have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    created_at TEXT NOT NULL, 
    uuid TEXT NOT NULL, 
    val INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(created_at, uuid));
```

Querying like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at > '2018-01-01' AND uuid = 'abc'
```

will use the primary key index.

But what if i only search on uuid for instance?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uuid = 'abc'
```

Should i recreate an index on the uuid column alone or the primary index will just works fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at > '2018-01-01' AND uuid = 'abc';
--EQP-- 0,0,0,SEARCH TABLE mytable USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1 (created_at>?)
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uuid = 'abc';
--EQP-- 0,0,0,SCAN TABLE mytable
```

However, in some circumstances, the PK index [might be used](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#skipscan):

> SQLite might use a skip-scan on an index if it knows that the first one or more columns contain many duplication values. […]
>   The only way that SQLite can know that the left-most columns of an index have many duplicate is if the [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) command has been run on the database.

Depending on the queries you run, it might be a better idea to make `uuid` the first column of the primary key constraint.